# SVN commit command

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to commit the folder after adding some new files to that folder. When I tried this in [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN), it was working properly (committed successfully), but while trying this by using the `svn commit` command it did not commit the folder.

Steps I have followed are:

1. Checkout the test folder from the repository, to `D:\Test` folder,
2. Add some new files to that test folder,
3. Commit that folder using `svn.exe commit D:\Test -m "Added"`.

It was not committed. I have tried this in TortoiseSVN (right-click on that folder and click SVN Commit), and it committed successfully.

Comment: 19 questions, plenty of answers; accept some please.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question on svnforum.org](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/45870-svn-commit-command?p=127401&viewfull=1#post127401)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To add a file/folder to the project, a good way is:

First of all add your files to /path/to/your/project/my/added/files, and then run following commands:

```
svn cleanup /path/to/your/project

svn add --force /path/to/your/project/*

svn cleanup /path/to/your/project

svn commit /path/to/your/project -m 'Adding a file'
```

I used cleanup to prevent any [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (core dumped), and now the SVN project is updated.

Comment: When I use ```svn add --force D:\ABC\sample\v1.0.0``` command I am getting ```svn: E155007: 'D:\ABC' is not a working copy directory```. Any solution for this

Comment: In my case on Windows, putting the commit message into single quotes lead to an error. I succeeded with putting everything into double quotes like e.g. `"c:\path\to\svn.exe" commit "c:\path\to\your\project" -m "Adding a file."`.

Answer (score 13):

#### Command-line SVN

You need to add your files to your working copy, before you commit your changes to the repository:

```
svn add <file|folder>
```

Afterwards:

```
svn commit
```

See [here](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) for detailed information about `svn add`.

**TortoiseSVN**

It works with TortoiseSVN, because it adds the file to your working copy automatically (commit dialog):

> If you want to include an unversioned file, just check that file to add it to the commit.

See: [TortoiseSVN: Committing Your Changes To The Repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

First add the new files:

```
svn add fileName
```

Then commit all new and modified files

```
svn ci <files_separated_by_space> -m "Commit message|ReviewID:XXXX"
```

If non source files are to be committed then

```
svn ci <files> -m "Commit msg|ReviewID:NON-SOURCE"
```

Answer (score -1):

Step1. $ cd [your working path of code]

Step2. $ svn commit [your server path ] -m 'Add commit message'

For help use $ svn help commit